# Selenium with JUnit - Embedding tests within a test flow (Java)

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit

This is my first question, so apologies if I am asking a simple question, but I haven't found a solution - probably just thinking about it wrong.

I have a test suite for creating user accounts via the front end UI, with many pages in between.  Right now I am testing the functionality (account is created correctly, etc.) separate from the UI (correct messaging, formatting, etc).

I would like to find a way to combine these flows so I am not creating an account and going through the entire flow just for UI tests.  This seems like a waste of time when I could just verify the UI elements as I am going through the functionality tests.

Can anyone point me to documentation/javadocs with tools to accomplish this?

Comment: I feel this post is not getting much attention because it is a bit vague. Can you specify the technologies you are using? What do you mean by testing separately the functionality and the UI? How do you test the functionality? Through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the session in your testcase and use the same session_id in subsequent tests, this way you don't always have to log in/register.

Or you could use the "browserSessionReuse" option with Selenium. This prevents the browser from closing in between tests, so you always test with the current session.